# Where are my old reminders on my iPhone 6 after upgrading the list on my iPhone 14 Pro Max?

Tags: iphone, ios, reminders

I have two iPhones. An old iPhone 6 `iOS:12.5.6` and a new iPhone 14 Pro Max.

I clicked something like "do you want to upgrade" on the iPhone 14 Pro Max, and then got a notification on my old iPhone 6.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

After the upgrade, I LOST everything on my old iPhone 6. And I have read through the link: https://support.apple.com/en-hk/HT210220 but couldn't find a way to restore them.

Where are the old reminders? Have I lost them permanently?

Update:

I have tried this:

1, logged in my iCloud.

[image]

2. restored the reminder on the date that I click "upgrade"

[image]

Comment: The Apple KB you link tells you exactly what's happened to them, & your only workaround if you don't have the minimum iOS 13.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for your reply, but I'm sorry that I couldn't find the workaround. Could you please help with more details?

Comment: You need to access it via a web browswer. The iPhone can no longer see or handle the data in its new form.

Comment: May I ask what URL I should use? Thanks.

Comment: The link is right there on the KB from your question.

Comment: I tried all the links on that page. I logged in icloud and restored "calendar and reminder", but still not working. I can't access the old data.

Comment: *restored "calendar and reminder"* How? There's nothing to 'restore'. You can now only see the data on the web page. Your iPhone can no longer see it directly.

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: The KB page tells you *exactly* what you can & can't do. You can't 'restore' them because there's nothing to restore. They are no longer accessible from any device running iOS 12, unless you go directly to https://www.icloud.com/#reminders in a web browser & view them from there. This is all clearly explained in the KB article. I have no idea where you got the idea they could be 'restored'.

Comment: I tried to find the data on  icloud.com/#reminders but couldn't find anything. That's why I am trying to restore it. Does this mean I have lost the data permanently? Thanks for your patience very much!

Comment: Please ignore my previous words. I have called the service, and they told me there is no way to recover the lost data. But I am lucky enough to restore the iPhone from a backup created a week ago. So I got the data back and saved them manually. Thanks for your previous comments.